# How to handle Geo Location pop up in android + Appium + C#+Chrome

Tags: c#, mobile, automation, geolocation, appium

I am facing issue in handling Geo Location pop up in Chrome mobile browser. My framework is C# based.

[image]

I tried clicking using id, class name etc. But throwing No element exception error.
Also i tried passing chrome capabilities for autoGrantPermissons, autoAcceptAlerts, AllowGeoLocation etc. but nothing worked.

I am trying to execute using real device.
PFB the details:
Android Version: 6.0.1
Chrome Version: 64.0.3282.137

Appium Version: 1.7.1
Selenium version: 3.0.1

Could any one please help with the same as this is really important for my project.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you also tried to get it by name? `driver.findElement(By.name("LocationPopup")).click();` Could you post what identifiers the popup has with a GUI-Inspector? It's also possible you need to switch to the alert first : `driver.switch_to_alert()` <- python syntax though

Comment: Yes.. I tried using switchto(), clicking using id etc. but nothing worked.